# I want to configure the keycloak client tab with the krakend API gateway,

Tags: keycloak, krakend

I want to configure the keycloak client tab with the krakend API gateway, I can't find documentation how to configure mainly the fields "Redirect URI", "Root URL" and Valid redirect URIs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwoLf.png)

Version

Krakend  2.1
Keycloak  21.0.1

thank you for your valuable comments

I have configured the krakend address, but I have not been able to authenticate.